# Android GPS accuracy not even close to built in maps app

Tags: android, gps, location, device

I've been experimenting with the Android SDK for a few weeks now, trying to achieve an accurate location from a background service.

After trying a few configurations, I currently have this on a loop:

```
Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
criteria.setAltitudeRequired(false);
criteria.setBearingRequired(true);
criteria.setCostAllowed(true);
criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_HIGH);
bestProvider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
lastKnownLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(bestProvider);
```

And then I check `lastKnownLocation` every now and then for a position update. I know you can listen for updates but at the moment I'm not too concerned about that right now. What I am concerned about is, (I think) I'm asking for the phone to use GPS whenever possible - instead of other methods of determining the location - an yet it still returns a latitude / longitude from a good distance away, yet when I open the maps application, it has me within a couple of meters.

Can anyone suggest where I'm going wrong here?

Comment: If you're only presenting the logic, you're correct, though I'll prefer setAltitudeRequired(true) even though it's not needed.

Comment: Does it do anything special except the obvious?

Comment: To be sure if you are asking for GPS log in logCat your bestProvider string. Second, you only use getLastKnownLocation? Why not use requestLocationUpdates and LocationListener?

Comment: Please try to get your first 'accurate location' by requestLocationUpdates() and onLocationChanged() especially when using GPS. The device need some time to locate itself.

Comment: As I mentioned above, I know about this I'm just not using it right now. I had this setup a couple of days ago and experienced exactly the same results.

Comment: I agree your logic looks right and almost identical to mine. I know you are unconcerned about updates, but what minDistance do you set in requestLocationUpdates, as that might not register small changes in 'accuracy'?

Comment: Good point, I'll retest it to use that and see what results I get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the Criteria just establishes which provider is best to use depending on them so that doesn't really have a say on the accuracy or the validity of the location. I just set the provider to GPS straight away (If GPS is available!).

Also it doesn't seem like your giving it any requirements concerning how long you want to wait before updating based on time and distance. Here is an example of what I do using intents and broadcast receiver. It may help you.

```
public void beginMonitoringLocation(int minDistance) {
            IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
            filter.addAction(MainActivity.LOCATION_UPDATE_ACTION);
            this.mContext.registerReceiver(this.locationReceiver, filter);

            LocationManager mLocationManager = (LocationManager) this.mContext.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            mLocationManager.addGpsStatusListener(this);
            boolean enabled =  mLocationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

            if (!enabled) {
                Log.e("LocationManager", "GPS not enabled!!!!");
            } 

            LocationProvider provider = mLocationManager.getProvider(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER); // GET THE BEST PROVIDER FOR OUR LOCATION
            Log.d("LocationManager:","Location Provider:"+provider);
            if ( provider == null ) {
                Log.e( "LocationManager", "No location provider found!" );
                return;
            }

            final int locationUpdateRC=0;

            int flags = 0;

            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.LOCATION_UPDATE_ACTION); 
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.mContext, locationUpdateRC, intent, flags); 
            // PENDING INTENT TO BE FIRED WHEN THE LOCATIONMANAGER RECEIVES LOCATION UPDATE.
            // THIS PENDING INTENT IS CAUGHT BY OUR BROADCAST RECEIVER
            mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,0,minDistance,pendingIntent);
            this._monitoringLocation = true;
    }
```

And then in the same class I put my `broadcast receiver`

```
public BroadcastReceiver locationReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Location location = (Location) intent.getExtras().get(LocationManager.KEY_LOCATION_CHANGED);
        if (location != null) {
            //Do something with it  
        }
        }
    };
```

The action for my intent filter is just a static reference to a constant set in my activity.

```
public static final String LOCATION_UPDATE_ACTION = "com.corecoders.sqlmaptrack.LOCATION_UPDATE_RECEIVED";
```

This worked in my case in providing me with accurate locations. You can set the distance to 0 if you want then what you will find is you get location fixes of an accuracy of 5 every second if you have a good fix of 4 satellites or more.

I hope this helps you

Comment: Thanks. Will this work inside my service or do I need to run it from an activity?

Comment: I can't see any reason why it wouldn't. I run mine just in my activity because it still runs in the background due to it using a pending intent and broadcast receiver

Comment: Ah OK, I'll try that instead of my service then.

Comment: Sorry you can disregard that. That listens to the status of the GPS for things like number of satellites etc.

Comment: Ah OK, I removed the comment - I was just reading about and decided it was a silly question from me ;)

Comment: Just about to run this, the only problem I've come across is `filter.addaction()`. What is `MainActivity.LOCATION_UPDATE_ACTION`, does it not call a method?

Comment: Added the creation of the static constant I use for the intent filter that I forgot to mention to the answer

Comment: I think I'm doing something wrong. I've used your code and made my activity `implement LocationListener`. Then I'm just logging a message on `onLocationChanged` and it's not firing. Nor is the broadcast receiver. I've set the string to `my.package.LOCATION_UPDATE_RECEIVED`.

Comment: You don't need to implement LocationListener. Its the broadcast recevier thats going to receive the location. So you need to make sure GPS is enabled for your device. Also make sure you call `beginMonitoringLocation(0)`. Obviously mContext is the same as calling `this.getApplicationContext()` in an `Activity` its just mines in a separate class. All that ok?

Comment: I did think that - I've removed it anwyay. I'm not sure if my device is playing up here because it started working without my changing any code! Thanks :D

Comment: I've just noticed it can take a while - up to 30 seconds from startup. Maybe I was being impatient! Thanks anyway!

Comment: Depends where you're testing. inside obviously the satellites can't get you. Outside they can!

Answer (score 1):

I have used the below code to get accurate location. Using below code you can handle enabling/disabling the GPS programmatically.

```
private void enableGPSTracking() {

            new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                super.run();
                try {
                    toggleGPS(true, getApplicationContext());

                    provider = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;
                    Criteria locationCritera = new Criteria();
                    locationCritera.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
                    locationCritera.setAltitudeRequired(false);
                    locationCritera.setBearingRequired(false);
                    locationCritera.setCostAllowed(true);                   locationCritera.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.NO_REQUIREMENT);
                    provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(locationCritera,
                            true);

                    Intent intent = new Intent(
                            "com.example.gps.LOCATION_READY");
                    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                            getApplicationContext(), 0, intent,
                            PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
                    // Register for broadcast intents
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 0, 0,
                            pendingIntent);
                } catch (Exception e) {

                }

            }
        }.start();

    }

public static void toggleGPS(boolean flag, Context context) {

        try {
            Intent intent = new Intent("android.location.GPS_ENABLED_CHANGE");
            intent.putExtra("enabled", flag);
            context.sendBroadcast(intent);
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }
```

to disable the GPS, simply pass false for flag value of ToggleGPS() method. Hope this helps you.